# trying to pass a jquery variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wordpress archive of past posts and want to change which post is featured at the top. I have collected the post id into a variable (wordp_id) and now want to use that change the post number where it says  to "p=55" to whatever the variable is. here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wp_arch_title').click(function(){

        var wordp_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#var_print').html(wordp_id);

    });
});
</script>

<h1 style="font-size:5em;">News Archive</h1>
<h2>All our posts for you to catch up on</h2>          

<?php query_posts('p=59'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2 class="wp_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>


<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=&order=DSC&orderby=date&category_name=news');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

        <p class="wp_arch_date">
        <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
        <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> -->
        <?php echo ' - '; ?>       </p>

        <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="wp_arch_title">
        <?php the_title(); ?></h2>


        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <div id="wp_border"></div>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: where that variable? in the url? in the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery runs client side in the browser while php runs server side. The only way to get a variable into php from a web page is send it to the server for the php script to work on. That is what your doing in the code you posted that you said worked.

If you want to do it without actually refreshing/changing the page you'll need to look at using ajax (http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax ) to call a php page and get information back. There are several tutorials here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials that can help you get started.